# How to do logging in botframework composer 2.0.0?

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I have read the issue here https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3286#issuecomment-638601360. Does anyone have detailed steps on how to do the logging? When I add the blobstorage settings to advanced settings json it does not log into the blob container. Do I need to add additional code to `startup.cs` or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the settings:

- blobStorage is used to enable TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.
- cosmosDb is used to store user and conversation data.
- applicationInsights is used to enable the telemetry logger.

Only changes for activating the transcript logging into blob storage is adding these settings in appsettings json file:

```
"applicationInsights": {
  "InstrumentationKey": "*******************************"
},
"cosmosDb": {
  "cosmosDBEndpoint": "****",
  "authKey": "****",
  "databaseId": "botstate-db",
  "collectionId": "botstate-collection",
  "containerId": "botstate-container"
},
"blobStorage": {
  "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=********;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "container": "transcripts"
}
```